# How to store bitmap assets in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bitmap, bitblt

I used to use VB 6.0 and now I'm switching to .net and I'm finding lots of things have changed. Back in the day, I used to store graphics assets in pictureboxes, make them invisible, and then bitblt them to the form / screen / canvas when I needed to. This was a nice, tidy way of doing it but now I'm trying to do the same thing in VB.NET and it wont work.

If the picturebox is on screen and visible, everything works perfectly, however making the picturebox invisible or moving it offscreen messes up the graphics that bitblt draws. I can successfully load a bitmap that's stored externally, but what I wanted to know was, what is the best way to store graphics (bitmap) assets inside a VB.NET application for use with bitblt?

for reference, here is a code snippet:

```
#Region " Members "
Public mouseX As Integer
Public mouseY As Integer

Public srcGraphics As Graphics
Public TargetGraphics As Graphics
Public srcHdc As IntPtr
Public targetHdc As IntPtr
Public srcSize As Size
Private blnShowWheel As Boolean

#End Region

#Region " Internals "
Const SRCCOPY As Integer = &HCC0020
' Wraping things up
Private Sub MyBitBlt(ByVal SourceGraphics As Graphics, ByVal TargetHDC As IntPtr, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer)
    ' Creating a DeviceContext to capture from
    Dim SourceHDC As IntPtr = SourceGraphics.GetHdc
    ' Blitting (Copying) the data
    BitBlt(TargetHDC, 0, 0, width, Height, SourceHDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
    ' Releasing the Device context used
    SourceGraphics.ReleaseHdc(SourceHDC)
End Sub
Private Sub MyBitBlt(ByVal SourceHDC As IntPtr, ByVal TargetHDC As IntPtr, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer, ByVal PosX As Integer, ByVal PosY As Integer)
    ' Copying data to a specific position on the target Device Context
    BitBlt(TargetHDC, PosX, PosY, width, Height, SourceHDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
End Sub

' Cleanning Up
' Before Destroying this class, dispose of objects to reclaim memory
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    DisposeObjects()
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub

' Disposing of objects
Private Sub DisposeObjects()
    TargetGraphics.Dispose()
    srcGraphics.Dispose()
End Sub

#End Region

Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
    Finalize()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Finalize()
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Width = 800
    Me.Height = 600
    Me.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - Me.Width) / 2
    Me.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - Me.Height) / 2

    srcSize = picColourWheel.Size
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    srcGraphics = picColourWheel.CreateGraphics
    TargetGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    srcHdc = srcGraphics.GetHdc
    targetHdc = TargetGraphics.GetHdc

    If Not blnShowWheel = True Then
        blnShowWheel = True
    Else
        blnShowWheel = False
    End If

    If blnShowWheel = True Then
        MyBitBlt(srcHdc, targetHdc, srcSize.Width, srcSize.Height, mouseX - (srcSize.Width / 2), mouseY - (srcSize.Height / 2))
    Else
        Me.Refresh()
    End If

    srcGraphics.ReleaseHdc(srcHdc)
    TargetGraphics.ReleaseHdc(targetHdc)
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    mouseX = e.X
    mouseY = e.Y
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using BitBlt() simply because you used it before in VB6?  This is a temporary drawing (it would be erased if you minimized/restored).  Do you need a persistent drawing?

Comment: I guess a good explanation would be because I have a graphic interface over which I'll be rendering a colour wheel, when a user clicks on a tile. then the user selects a colour from the colour wheel, the colour wheel goes away and the tile changes to that colour. The reasons I am using bitblt is because A) I need to be able to mask the transparent areas around the colour wheel, and B) I need to be able to refresh the screen and redraw the wheel where ever the user clicks. I think I'm doing the right thing and at the moment I can load a BMP into a picbox and bitblt the contents of a picbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, Right Click the Project --> Add --> Existing Item --> Select Image.
Select newly added Image entry in Solution Explorer.
Down below in the Properties Pane, change "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource".
Now the image will be embedded in the application, and you can draw it like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.GetType, "Smiley1.jpg") ' <-- Exactly as it appears in Solution Explorer (it IS cAsE-sEnSiTiVe!)
        Using G As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
            G.DrawImage(bmp, New Point(25, 25))
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Wow, that is so much neater than how I used to do it! Makes sense too, rather than clogging up the form with unnecessary pictureboxes. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Not sure exactly what your architecture is, but in general using CreateGraphics() isn't the right approach for drawing on controls.  Instead, store info about what needs to be drawn at class level (like a List of something), then use "e.Graphics" from the Paint() event of the control and use that information to draw what is necessary.  This way it will be persistent and won't disappear when you minimize/restore.

Comment: OK, cool I'll look into it. I guess what I'm trying to do is take the bitmap (called ColorWheel.bmp) and bitblt it with a mask into the form background. This way, I'll have a transparent area around the bitmap. Is this the best way to go about it? Also, once I get the bitmap, how do I turn it into a graphics file that I can use with bitblt? Sorry, I'm still very new to .net

Comment: Once you've got "bmp", just call [MakeTransparent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds.aspx) against it and then call DrawImage() as before.

Comment: how do I determine what area of the bitmap would be transparent and what would be opaque? for clarification, the image to be rendered is a circle.

Comment: That would be completely dependent upon the image.  Often times the color in the top left of the image is used as the "mask" color.  So the part you want to keep is in the middle, and it is completely surrounded by the mask color which gets removed.  In this [Globe](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/bitmaps/resources/globe.bmp), the color black could be specified so that you could overlay it like [this](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/bitmaps/forms/transparent2.gif).